# Centos5 - Can ping by IP but not hostname

Tags: centos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to resolve hostname to ip](https://superuser.com/questions/434513/unable-to-resolve-hostname-to-ip)

I have a centos 5 box and can ping outside by IP but not by hostname.

For example, ping to a known server works fine using IP but not with HOSTNAME.

Any ideas how to trouble shoot this?  Other computers inside the network are fine.

Thanks,
Graham

Comment: What error are you receiving? hostname unreachable?

Comment: Would you perhaps be so polite as to mark the answer as such? :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an incorrect dns server set. Check /etc/resolv.conf and make sure `nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is your actual DNS server